# KeyListener doesn't work on java .awt.Window

Tags: java, java-me, cdc

I am using a `java.awt.Window` for my CDC application.
Now I have opted java.awt.Window because, I wanted a non draggable, non resizeable window for my app and `frame.setUndecorated()` is not available in CDC apis.

Now the problem is any keypress doesn't work on my window. I have implemented `keyListener` and override all methods. still no clue why it behaves so. :(

Note : I am developing this app in J2ME - CDC with Personal profile and not in Java

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved! Discovered that KeyListener on a java.awt.Window works only if following conditions are met:

1. The owning window/frame of the present Window(which has to handle events) has to be setVisible(true)
2. The owning window/frame need to have at least one focusable component.